# How to stop Dreamweaver from converting " double quotes to &quot;?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, html-entities

I need to use double quotes inside a tag

How to stop Dreamweaver from converting " double quotes to **`&quot;`** ?

I need the original " and not **`&quot`**; but as soon as I add the " quote via Design view, it shows " in design view, but in code view its **`&quot`**;

I need the " double quote to remain the same in both Design and Code view.

The reason is that i need the double quote "" in a tag  such as **`{mytag category="news"}`**

I need the exact tag as **`{mytag category="news"}`** but dreamweaver is changing the double quotes in the Code view to **`&quot;`** so this is what i am getting in the Code view

`{mytag category=&quot;news&quot;}`

**ISSUE :: SOLVED**

Comment: can you just add the quotes into the html in code view?

Comment: @imjared Yes, i can but i am trying to a toolbar tag in dreamweaver which inputs the tag automatically. This is where the problem is arising

Comment: Don't use designer view unless you're just adding static content. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

I just changed the DOCTYPE from XHTML to HTML5

And it worked fine, it did not convert the double quotes to its entity.

This solves the issue for me, for now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this.

In HTML

```
foo='"'
```

and

```
foo='&quot;'
```

are equivalent. If you need one of those two syntaxes over the other, then you are not dealing with HTML and shouldn't be using an HTML editor to produce your content.

```
foo="""
```

… on the other hand, is an error and you should have even less reason to want that.

Comment: I just added the detail to my original question

Comment: My point still stands, `&quot;` is HTML for `"`. Except in places where `"` has special meaning (such as when used as an attribute delimiter) they can be used interchangeably and any tool parsing the data must be able to cope with that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable this quote-pairing as follows :

1. Quit Dreamweaver.
2. Edit the text file: `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver CC 2017/en_US/Configuration/Brackets/brackets.json`
3. Add the following line within the body: `"closeBrackets": false,`
4. Save the text file and relaunch Dreamweaver.

It should no longer auto-complete quote pairs.

Some people have reported they needed to make this change to the same-named file within the application folder as shown below, but I had no such file on my UK installation:

`Applications\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2017\en_US\Configuration\Brackets\brackets.json`